# Unattended Bluetooth file transfers

Tags: bluetooth

Thanks to all who understood my dilemma and frustration. To the rest, well, may your chickens grow into Turkeys and kick your chicken shed down.

I am using Mint 19.1 -- OK, so I know this is not a Mint forum, but the Mint forum is not able or willing to help, so Mint being based on Ubuntu, here I am.

We have had Ubuntu in our household for many years and I am just testing Mint. When I send files from my phone via BT, Mint asks me to approve the transfer so I have to be sitting in front of the computer. DUH!

In Ubuntu that is an option in the Personal File Sharing where I can uncheck "Notify ..." so I am guessing that option still exists within Mint.

How do I find it and how do I stop it asking if it is OK?

Thanks

Comment: We do not support Mint here. You can read about why, if you are interested, in, for example, [this meta post](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/5881/527764). You can ask questions about Mint on [unix.se] (or [SU]).

Comment: The option you speak of doesn't exist in Ubuntu 18.04 so it is not just a Mint issue

Answer (score 1):

This has been tested in Ubuntu 16.04 and may/may not work in your (Mint's) case.

Install blueman package using    `sudo apt-get install blueman`.

Open the corresponding Bluetooth Manager.

After you confirm the pairing request, the device (your phone) will be listed in `Paired Devices`.

[image]Select your device and click on the star-shaped icon which represents the option to `Mark/Unmark the device as trusted`.

Interestingly, every time you pair (including the case when a connection is turned on/off from one end) you will have to accept the first transfer request. The subsequent requests will be processed based on the 'star' status of the device.
Check this [tutorial](https://jchaven.wordpress.com/2017/05/27/transfer-files-using-bluetooth-in-linux-mint/) as well.

Comment: Have you tested this?  Star shaped icon would involve installing Blueman

Comment: @Jeremy31 +1 for reminding me that Blueman is not there by default in either of the distributions. Also, if anyone wants to develop a more customized (and possibly smoother!) version, the project is available [here](https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman).